# Getting the current section that is in the viewport in React-Native sectionlist

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I want to detect which section of the react-native sectionlist is in the viewport.
[image]

Is there any solution?

Comment: did my solution work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what you can do

```
  render () {
    return (
      <SectionList
        onViewableItemsChanged={this.onCheckViewableItems}
        viewabilityConfig={{
          itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 50 //means if 50% of the item is visible
        }}
      />
    )
  }

onCheckViewableItems = ({ viewableItems, changed }) => {
        console.log("Visible items :", viewableItems)
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that the section provide its sections from data prop of the state.

```
state = { data: [...], contentSizeData: [], currentSection: 0 }
```

And assume that your `SectionList` is like that.

```
<SectionList
  onScroll={event => {    
     for (var _i = 0; _i < this.state.contentSizeData.length; _i++) {
      if (event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y < this.state.contentSizeData[_i]) {
           this.setState({ currentSection: _i });
           break;
          }
       }
    }}
    renderItem={({ item, index, section }) => {
      <ItemComponent />
    }}
    renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => {
      <HeaderComponent />
    }}
    sections={this.state.data}
/>
```

You must calculate the content size of the total `renderedItems` with including `renderedHeaders` and in onScroll method regarding to `contentOffset` of `SectionList` we can check out that which section it is.

Suppose that you have `2 sections` which has `3 items` with `headers`. Each `renderedItem` has height of `100` and headers has height of `20` which looks like to example of bottom.

[image]

Then you have to create a logic with a loop that calculate of the content sizes of each section (calculate each section's height with including its header)

```
    var _sizeArr = []
    for(var _iter = 0; _iter < this.state.data.length; _iter++){
      let cellsHeight = this.state.data[_iter].length * 100;
      let headerHeight = 20;
      var totalHeight = cellsHeight + headerHeight;
      if(_iter != 0){
         _sizeArr.push(totalHeight + _sizeArr[_iter-1]); 
      }else{
         _sizeArr.push(totalHeight); 
      }
     }
   this.setState({ contentSizeData: _sizeArr })
```

> Let's look at section's height
>
> For first one 20 (header component)  + 3 * 100 (item component) => 320
>
> And second one 20 (header component) + 3 * 100 (item component) => 320

In `this.state.contentSizeData` array includes 2 height such as `[320, 640]`. Second one contains own section's height and section height which before itself. This means we use `SectionList`'s `onScroll` method with looking at `contentOffset.y` and we can check that if `SectionList's y position` is between [0 - 320] so its in `Section 0` and if not loop iterate and check if its between `[320 - 640]`, if so its in `Section 1`.

```
onScroll = {event => {
    for (var _i = 0; _i < this.state.contentSizeData.length; _i++) {
       if (event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y < this.state.contentSizeData[_i]) {
           this.setState({ currentSection: _i });
           break;
        }
    }
}}
```

When you scroll in `SectionList`, it triggered `onScroll` method and you can see the `currentSection` in the state.